# Why does Perl `printf` change the value of my $variable?

Tags: perl, security

I am trying to wrap my head around what is happening in [this secure coding example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/perl/IDS30-PL.+Exclude+user+input+from+format+strings).

I rewrote the code to better support my question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $prompt = 'name%n';     # The bad coding practice from the exercise.
my $password = 'badpass';

my $is_ok = ($password eq "goodpass");
print Dumper( $is_ok );

print "\n$prompt: Password ok? $is_ok\n";
print Dumper( $is_ok );

$is_ok = ($password eq "goodpass");
printf "\n$prompt: Password ok? %d\n" , $is_ok;
print Dumper( $is_ok );
```

When I execute the script the output is as follows:

```
$ ./authenticate.pl
$VAR1 = '';

name%n: Password ok?
$VAR1 = '';
Missing argument in printf at ./authenticate.pl line 19.

name: Password ok? 0
$VAR1 = 5;
```

Clearly `$is_ok` is consumed by the `%n` in `$prompt` which leaves the `%d` without a matching argument. I wouldn't expect however to `$is_ok` change value, why is `$is_ok` set to `5` by the printf statement?

Comment: @ikegami you are correct, I'll change the text in my question. I believe the script in the example code on the linked website died when using `strict`. It was a left over from my efforts in reducing the code.

Answer (score 6):

Because that's what `%n` does.

[perldoc -f sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> ```
>            %n    special: *stores* the number of characters output so far
>                  into the next argument in the parameter list
> ```

The solution is:

```
printf "\n%s: Password ok? %d\n", $prompt, $is_ok;
```

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't think of experimenting with (and checking docs of) the `%n` in the format string. Indeed when I change it to `%i` the value isn't changed. I *assumed* it was similar to `%d` or `%n`.

Comment: Added fix to the answer.

Comment: @ikegami Actually the point that is made in the linked secure coding article is to not use `printf` when not absolutely necessary and use input sanitation.

Comment: @jippe, That's not true. It's funny that you should mention that after i showed I showed how to do it corrently. Sure, you shouldn't trust the user to provide the format string (though it's not nearly as unsafe as in C), but the format string is hardcoded in the solution.

Comment: @jippie Actually the point made is "Never call any formatted I/O function *with a format string containing user input.*" The format string in ikegami's example doesn't contain user input.

Comment: @ikegami Ah I see what you guys are aiming at. I didn't notice `$prompt` being moved out of the format string and added as an argument.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I misread the solution given. Thanks for helping point out.